# Sound not working on Windows but works on Linux

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, sound-card, alsa

I am facing a strange problem where sound isn't working in windows. I first faced this issue in Windows 10 when I started my PC after a month and voila there was no sound. I hadn't started my computer for a month. While before the audio was working.
I installed all sort of drivers from official HP to Realtek and also Intel ones but none worked. My sound card is of Realtek and PC is HP pro 2000 MT. 
For finding if the issue were related to hardware I downloaded a linux distro(puppy linux) and sound works really well there. It means soundcard is working. 
I even restored Windows 10 but still the problem persists.. I even installed windows XP and still no sound there. Now in windows 7 again there is no sound while the driver status shows ok. Even the volume bar jumps when I play something but I can't hear anything.
What can I do to solve the problem? Why is there such a problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's strange you're asking this here I'll try and help you on your way anyways.

Try out [drp.su](http://drp.su) , make sure though you de-select all the crap it tries to install though.

Quote from the drp.su website:

> DriverPack allows you to configure your computer in one click, even
>   without thinking about the system configuration. At the same time the
>   program has a mode for advanced users with additional features.

There isn't a lot of information on the website and the software might look like crapware because of the broken English (Russian developer), but it is fantastic software which is also really easy to use. Simply install it like you would any other program and after running it go through the steps on the left. If you're just using it for driver installation make sure you de-select all the software install items and hit the big green install button.

PS: DRP.su only runs on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I will be installing it now.. Well I found other questions like this on super user website therefore I thought I would get an answer here :)... Sorry if it is something bad.

Comment: No worries always glad to (try and) help.

Comment: Its freaking amazing! The hell I wasted so many days installing windows and drivers.. My problem is solved now..

Comment: Thank you very much.. The problem is solved after the software installed about 13 different drivers.

Comment: =D I really like that tool for installing my clients pc's too!